# Is it possible to create textfield , buttons dynamically from the json response swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, view

I need to create views dynamically in coding in iOS Swift 2 which should be done from the json response.So if the json response consist of type button. I need to create button. Is it possible or is there any library available?

So If I have a json response like this

```
[{"type":"label","title":"First Name","id":"1"},{"type":"label","title":"Last Name","id":"2"}]
```

how can I add two labels with these titles in swift 2

Comment: can you post json response??

Comment: Also provide json response

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

The point is: how do you want that ui element to be created?

You can use information in the JSON to make a hidden button visible and giving to it the label value you have in the JSON response.

Or you can use something like https://github.com/146BC/StyleKit to have complete control on the style of the UI element setting in the JSON all the relevant details.

You should, probably, give us more details.